# Implementing IRandomAccessStream, not copying buffers

Tags: c#, .net, stream, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I'm a bit confused with what I'm supposed to do with `targetBuffer` in `ReadAsync()` implementation (Unversal store application for win 8.1).

```
public IAsyncOperationWithProgress<IBuffer, uint> ReadAsync(IBuffer targetBuffer, uint count, InputStreamOptions options)
```

The problem is, I can't find a way to write to `targetBuffer` and to change its `Length` given my specific implementation requirements.

What I have inside is an encrypted stream with some block cipher. I want to wrap it with IRandomAccessStream, so it can be used with xaml framework components (*such as passing encrypted images/video to `Image` or `MediaElement` objects*). Inside the class I have an array of bytes which I reuse for every block, passing it to encryption library which fills it and reports chunk size.

So, when `IRandomAccessStream.ReadAsync()` is called, I need to somehow get my bytes into the `targetBuffer` and set its `Length` to proper value... Which I don't seem to manage.

I tried this:

```
var stream = targetBuffer.AsStream();
while(count > 0) {
  /* doing something to get next chunk of data decrypted */
  // byte[] chunk is the array used to hold decrypted data
  // int chunkLength is the length of data (<= chunk.Length)

  count -= chunkLength;
  await stream.WriteAsync(chunk, 0, chunkLength);
}
return targetBuffer;
```

And `targetBuffer.Length` remains zero, yet if I try to print its content, the data is there!

```
Debug.WriteLine(targetBuffer.GetByte(0..N));
```

I now have a naïve implementation that uses a memory stream (in addition to byte array buffer), collects data there and reads back from it to `targetBuffer`. This works, but looks bad. Managed streams write to `byte[]` and WinRT streams write to `IBuffer`, and I just can't find a way around, so that I don't waste memory and performance.

I'd appreciate any ideas.

This is what it looks like now. I end up using a byte array as a decryption buffer and a resizeable memory stream as a proxy.

```
public IAsyncOperationWithProgress<IBuffer, uint> ReadAsync(IBuffer targetBuffer, uint count, InputStreamOptions options)
{
  return AsyncInfo.Run<IBuffer, uint>(async (token, progress) => {
    Transport.Seek(0); // Transport is InMemoryRandomAccessStream
    var remaining = count;
    while(remaining > 0) {    
      /*
      ReadAsync() overload reads & decrypts data, 
      result length is <= remaining bytes,
      deals with block cipher alignment and the like
      */
      IBuffer chunk = await ReadAsync(remaining); 

      await Transport.WriteAsync(chunk);
      remaining -= chunk.Length;
    }
    Transport.Seek(0);
    // copy resulting bytes to target buffer
    await Transport.ReadAsync(targetBuffer, count, InputStreamOptions.None);
    return targetBuffer;
  });
}
```

**UPDATE:** I've tested the solution above with an encrypted image of 7.9Mb. I fed it to `Image` instance like this:

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
await image.SetSourceAsync(myCustomStream);
Img.Source = image; // Img is <Image> in xaml
```

All is Ok untill execution reaches `await Transport.ReadAsync(targetBuffer, count, InputStreamOptions.None);`: there memory consumption skyrockets (from around 33mb to 300+mb), which effectively crashes phone emulator (desktop version shows image alright, though memory is consumed just the same). The hell is going on there?!

**SOLVED in March 2017**

First, I somehow did not realize I could just set the `Length` directly after writing data to buffer. Second, if yoou do just about anything wrong in my case (custom `IRandomAccessStream` implementation is the source for a XAML `Image` element), the app crashes not leaving any logs and not showing any errors, so it's really hard to figure out what has gone awry.

This is what the code looks like now:

```
public IAsyncOperationWithProgress<IBuffer, uint> ReadAsync(IBuffer targetBuffer, uint count, InputStreamOptions options)
{
    return AsyncInfo.Run<IBuffer, uint>(async (token, progress) => {
        var output = targetBuffer.AsStream();
        while (count > 0) {
            //
            // do all the decryption stuff and get decrypted data
            // to a reusable buffer byte array
            //
            int bytes = Math.Min((int) count, BufferLength - BufferPosition);
            output.Write(decrypted, bufferPosition, bytes);
            targetBuffer.Length += (uint)bytes;
            BufferPosition += bytes;
            progress.Report((uint)bytes);
            count -= (uint)bytes;
        }
    }
    return targetBuffer;
});
```

Comment: How did you initial the `targetBuffer`? How can `targetBuffer.Length` be zero? I think using `targetBuffer` in `ReadAsync(...)` method, it should have a length of the parameter `uint count` .

Comment: I'm not creating targetBuffer at all. When you do `Image.SetSource(IRandomAccessStream)` or `MediaElement.SetSource(IRandomAccessStream, "video/mp4")` and pass your own stream implementation, `ReadAsync()` gets called with `targetBuffer.Length` being zero. When you read into buffer rom a winrt stream, the length gets properly set.

Comment: When you read into the buffer from a winrt stream, the length gets properly set, as shown in the code: `Transport.ReadAsync(targetBuffer ... )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;

`(your byte array).CopyTo(targetBuffer);`

the Length property in IBuffer has a setter

the following code is perfectly valid

`targetBuffer.Length = (your integer here)`

you have more variants of CopyTo to choose from. have a look at this one:

`public static void CopyTo(this byte[] source, int sourceIndex, IBuffer destination, uint destinationIndex, int count);`

Comment: Oh. :) I didn't realize I could just set Length directly after writing data to buffer. I updated the post to show what I do now. Thanks!